Error "This site can’t be reached, localhost refused to connect" after upgrading to Laravel 11 while sending data to Firestore
I am working on a Laravel project that uses Firebase Firestore to manage some data. Initially, I was using Laravel 9, and everything worked fine. However, after upgrading to Laravel 11, I encountered a problem.
When I try to send data to Firestore from Laravel, I receive the following error in my browser:
This site can’t be reached, localhost refused to connect.
Here is the code I’m using:
$section = Section::where('id', $brand->section_id)->first();
$testSection = 0;
$testSection = $brand->section_id == 0 
    ? [
        "id" => 0,
        "name" => "",
    ] 
    : [
        "id" => $section->id,
        "name" => $section->name,
    ];

$firestore = app('firebase.firestore')
    ->database()
    ->collection('brands')
    ->document($brand->id)
    ->set([
        "id" => $brand->id,
        "name" => $brand->name,
        "section" => $testSection,
        "image" => $brand->logo,
        "contained" => $brand->contained,
        "vue" => $brand->vue,
        "status" => $brand->status,
    ]);


Do you think the problem is: localhost should be working (and it is not) or I shouldn't be connecting to localhost?
